# Quand ou Qu'en je dis quelque chose ?

Tags: grammaire

Quelle phrase est correcte ?

- Quand je dis quelque chose
- Qu'en je dis quelque chose

Comment: Aucun des deux n'est une phrase complète. Par ailleurs, il faudrait du contexte. Je ne vois pas de contexte dans lequel le deuxième fragment serait correct, mais cela ne veut pas dire que le premier est le bon, ça dépend du contexte et du sens qu'on veut exprimer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely "Quand je dis quelque chose", which means "when I say something"